# phpmyadmin page shows source code, Ubuntu 16.04 installed with Vagrant and Puphpet

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I installed virtualbox and vagrant, then went to https://puphpet.com and downloaded a package with Ubuntu 16.04. The relevant parts of that package are PHP, MySQL and Apache. It works now, I managed to connect to the server and PHP is running correctly (I installed magento on it).

Now I'm trying to install phpmyadmin, however after running the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

When i go to http://{serverIP}/phpmyadmin/ I get the source code of the file that's supposed to be the phpmyadmin login page, like this:

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYHkv.png)

What could be causing this? It can't be that PHP isn't installed correclty, cause I managed to install Magento and it works fine, so what could be the problem?

Edit:

Also in the /etc/apache2/apache.conf file, I added this line at the end of the file:

```
Include "/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, I needed to run:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

I was missing that extension. Also after I installed that extension I got an error saying:

AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded.

I fixed that by runnning:

```
sudo a2dismod worker
```

Not sure why this happened.